# Code Igniter catch errors on inserting data (Active Record)

Tags: php, database, activerecord, error-handling, codeigniter-2

I am inserting data into my database using the following code:

```
$this->db->set('event_id', $event_id);
...
$this->db->set('creator_id', $creator_id);

$this->db->insert('event');
```

How can I make sure the process was successful and show the user a confirmation message, else an error message?

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($this->db->insert('event'));` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uhm, IIRC the method returns true if succesful, so you could go with a simple

```
if($this->db->insert('event'))
{
  echo 'Row succesfully inserted!';
}
```

Otherwise, you might always count the [**affected rows**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html):

```
//....
$this->db->insert('event');
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
  echo 'row succesfully inserted';
}
```

**UPDATE** after comment:

I believe your three insert_batch() are on three different tables, so a check should be down on each one. Anyway, what's puzzling me is the reason behin this check..Query don't fail randomly: possibily they should *never* fail and when they do you'll know through errors (logged or dislayed).

Comment: I have two insert_batch($array) after that, do I have to test each insert before doing another? Or can I just test them all 3, i.e.
   `if($this->db->insert('event') && $this->db->insert_batch($arr1) && $this->db->insert_batch($arr2)){...}`

Comment: A much better technique, if you are using several different inserts to different tables would be to use a transaction. These can be rolled back if one or more of the database queries fails. For details, see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html This will take all the effort out of "a check should be done on each one", and will result in a much cleaner solution.

Perhaps transactions were not available in CI when this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

"If you need to get the last error that has occurred, the error() method will return an array containing its code and message."
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

```
$insert = $this->db->insert('event');

             if(!$insert){

                $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
                echo "<BR><BR>";
                print_r($error);
                echo "<BR><BR>";
            }

            echo "Error contact the database admin.";
            die();

        }else{

            echo "SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED ITEM";
            return TRUE;
        }
```